# Use behave tags to execute only a subcase of such tag

Tags: python, python-behave

I have the following scenario definition in a `sample.feature` file, with scenario with two sub-cases using the `Examples` syntax:

```
  @ninja
  Scenario Outline: this is a sample scenario
    Given ...
    And ...
    And ..
    When ...
    Then ...

    Examples:
      | param1 | param2 | param3 |
      |     10 |      4 |      9 | 
      |     20 |      8 |     23 |
```

I can use the tag `ninja` to execute only that scenario, among all the others defined in the `sample.feature` file, as follows:

```
$ behave sample.feature --tags=ninja
...
Scenario Outline: this is a sample scenario -- @1.1
...
Scenario Outline: this is a sample scenario -- @1.2
...
```

Note that behave "marks" each subcase execution, i.e. `@1.1` and `@1.2` in execution log.

I'd like to know if I can be even more "sharp" and use behave to execute only one (or a subset) of subcases of a given tag. I have tried the following, with no luck (i.e. both subcases are executes, not only the second one):

```
$ behave sample.feature --tags=ninja,1.2
```

Is that possible? Any help on how doing it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to execute only one row in a Scenario Outline (Examples), first is necessary to define a placeholder in the tag into the feature file, example:
       **`@test.row<row.id>`** [Reference in Behave](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/new_and_noteworthy_v1.2.5.html#tags-may-contain-placeholders)

After, to execute:

> behave example.feature -t **`@test.row1.2`**  *-- run only the row: 2 with this tag.*

Also it is posible create several examples, like this:

```
    Examples:
      | param1 | param2 | param3 |
      |     10 |      4 |      9 | 
      |     20 |      8 |     23 |
    Examples:
      | param1 | param2 | param3 |
      |     30 |     12 |      1 | 
      |     40 |     13 |     45 |
      |     50 |     14 |     49 | 
      |     60 |     15 |     13 |
```

And,

> behave example.feature -t **`@test.row2.4`**  *-- run only the row: 4 in the second examples with this tag:*

```
      |     60 |     15 |     13 |
```