# Tag different sets of example in behave test differently

Tags: python, tags, python-behave

I have a springboot service that can be booted with different `spring.profiles.active`. The service was initially created to start with `spring.profiles.active=profile1`. Someone then added `behave` test/scenarios for the service.

Later, I added another profile to the service and now I want to run the behave tests for both profiles. So, first run behave tests when the service is started with `spring.profiles.active=profile1` and then run the tests again with service started with `spring.profiles.active=profile2`.

I can run behave tests twice and use environment variables to control the spring profiles settings. I can also tag my scenarios differently for the two profiles like

```
@profile1
Scenario Outline: test something in profile1
  Given: blah
  ...


@profile2
Scenario Outline: test something in profile2
  Given: blah
  ...

Then run behave tests twice as
>> behave --tags=profile1
>> behave --tags=profile2
```

However, there is a lot of scenarios that are common across both profiles and it does not make sense to repeat those with different `tags`. For example,

```
Scenario Outline: test that a user is recommended at least 10 items
  Given a user <userId>
  when recommendations are generated
  then at least 10 items are returned in the recommendations

Examples:
|userId|
|123456| # I want to use this userId for profile1
|234567| # and this one too for profile1
|987654| # but this one and the following for profile2
|876543|
```

A similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45186323/use-behave-tags-to-execute-only-a-subcase-of-such-tag) provides a solution like

```
Scenario Outline: test that a user is recommended at least 10 items
  Given a user <userId>
  when recommendations are generated
  then at least 10 items are returned in the recommendations

Examples:
|userId|
|123456| # I want to use this userId for profile1
|234567| # and this one too for profile1

Examples:
|userId|
|987654| # but this one and the following for profile2
|876543|

and then use `row2.4` etc to call specific row of examples for the second profile.
```

This, however, does not appear elegant to me (what if I disable or rearrange the examples later?).

My question is, is there a way to tag specific example rows?

So, something along the line of

```
Examples: @profile1
|userId|
|123456| # I want to use this userId for profile1
|234567| # and this one too for profile1

Examples: @profile2
|userId|
|987654| # but this one and the following for profile2
|876543|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, is there a way to tag specific example rows?

You were really close.

```
@profile1
Examples: 
|userId|
|123456| # I want to use this userId for profile1
|234567| # and this one too for profile1

@profile2
Examples: 
|userId|
|987654| # but this one and the following for profile2
|876543|
```

Although the appendix has a suggestion for userdata [implementation](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/new_and_noteworthy_v1.2.5.html#index-7) that might be useful for your example scenario. Or you might want to look at active tag matcher `@use.with_profile=profile1` below that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. from behave version 1.2.6 you can tag for each example. 
https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/new_and_noteworthy_v1.2.6.html  
 
Here is an example:

```
Scenario Outline: test that a user is recommended at least 10 items
Given a user <userId>
when recommendations are generated
then at least 10 items are returned in the recommendations
@profile1
Examples:
|userId|
|123456| # I want to use this userId for profile1
|234567| # and this one too for profile1

@profile2
Examples:
|userId|
|987654| # but this one and the following for profile2
|876543|
```